# Complex filter in jira

Tags: jira, bamboo, atlassian-crucible

I would like to create a filter that works like this :

For a given user, say user 'abc', I want to filter the user stories that have been assigned to him, were in progress state, and transitioned to Resolved state, there is a review attached to the JIRA and it is Closed, and ALL the commits from the review (that were added via Browse changeset) were merged in a specified branch (in bamboo) and the build passed. All this within a date period, say one month.

Also I would like to see all the commits that were made and didn't pass through a review, but they were nevertheless merged into a specified branch.

Can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just with a filter i think it is not possible. 
What do you have written so far?
Can you install plugins?
Can it be done with spcripts?
Wich filters are you using for this pourpouse? 
Are your fields jira fields, or are custom fields?

EDIT: **

Firstly you should ask for jira-admin privileges. After that install scriptrunner plugin. This plugin provides some prewritten functions available on JQL searches. I think that there is no function related to commits and deployments included. Anyway, your best choice is adding a Scripted Field(Provided on scriptrunner) and write your script because you can manage all information IN jira, using scripts. Your scripted field could set its value to built, merged, or wahtever you want, so that then your filter just should be something like:

```
YourScriptedField = "built"
```

On the other hand your current filter should be something like:

```
asignee was yourUser and status was "In Progress" and status = Closed and (status changed to Resolved after "yyyy-mm-dd" before "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: assignee = 'username' AND status was "In Progress" and status = "Resolved" -- that's about it, the rest, can't be filtered in the Advanced Search. I currently don't have admin privileges, but that's not an issue as I can request that. Installing plugins could be done. Jira & custom fields (in the future)

Comment: ScriptRunner roxx, if you plan to do reports at least this complex, start learning it: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview